# Reimplement Parent's attribute setter in Child using super()

Tags: python, python-3.x, super

I'd like to raise a `NotImplementedError` when trying to set an attribute in a child class. Here's the code:

```
class Parent():

    def __init__(self):
        self._attribute = 1

    @property
    def attribute(self):
        return self._attribute

    @attribute.setter
    def attribute(self, value):
        self._attribute = value


class Child(Parent):

    @Parent.attribute.setter
    def attribute(self, value):
        raise NotImplementedError('Not implemented.')
```

Is there a way to reimplement `Child`'s attribute setter using `super()`, instead of referencing `Parent` directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `super()` directly at the `class` statement block's top-level, since the `class` doesn't exist yet at this point.

The quick and simple solution is to make your `Parent` property setter delegate to another method, ie:

```
class Parent():
    def __init__(self):
        # note that you can use the property here,
        # no need to break encapsulation.
        self.attribute = 1

    @property
    def attribute(self):
        return self._attribute

    @attribute.setter
    def attribute(self, value):
        self._set(value) 

    def _set(self, value):
        self._attribute = value
```

Then you just have to override `_set(self)` in your child classes, like for any other ordinary method:

```
class Child(Parent):
    def _set(self, value):
        raise NotImplementedError
```